# Differentiating between user function returns and wrapping class returns

Tags: python, user-controls, standards

I'm having trouble developing a standard for returning data from user functions passed and executed in a class which runs the function as a separate thread.

The goal would be to pass the return arguments from the function when requested for by the user.

But what if the function is not finished running when the user requests data from my class? Or if the function fails and hence has no data (but its failure is not critical to the program, meaning raising an exception is excessive)

I had thought to just return None but what if the user function returns None and that is meaningful (ie the function completed successfully)? My next idea was to return the function output in a list and None if no data was ready or available. This would mean the user would have to check if the data was returned or not (check if None or a list) which I find slightly inelegant.

I am curious if there is already a standard for things like this or if anyone has a suggestion that is cleaner.

example:

user call

```
def foo():
    #...do lots of stuff that takes long time

    # return whether stuff worked or not (None if worked False if not)
    return success 

takes_forever = detach(foo)

# ... do other things

# get data from detached function which has hopefully completed
are_you_done = takes_forever.give_me_data()
```

My class:

```
class detach:
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.detached_func = execute_as_thread(func)

    def give_me_data(self) 
        if self.detached_func.is_done():        # function completed and didnt die
            return [self.detached_func.output]
        else:                                   # something went wrong or function is still running
            return None
```

Comment: You could try passing returns in a dict, maybe.  `return {'success': success, 'origin': origin ... etc, etc...}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best would be to raise exception, if for some reason you want to avoid that return a sepecial object e.g. define a class NoResultsType and return object of such type or may be just the class

```
class NoResultsType(object): pass

NoResults = NoResultsType()

def give_me_data(self) 
    if self.detached_func.is_done():        # function completed and didnt die
        return [self.detached_func.output]
    else:                                   # something went wrong or function is still running
        return NoResults
```

and then you can define multiple such types e.g. NoResults, FunctionFailed etc and user can just check them e.g.

```
ret = foo.give_me_data()
if ret in [NoResultsYet, FunctionFailed]:
   # do something
```

or you can return a Result object which can keep original result, states etc

```
class Result(object):
    def __init__(self):
         self.finished = False
         self.success = False
         self.error = ""
         self.result = None

res = foo.give_me_data()
if res.success:
    print res.result
```

Comment: After thinking about it a lot more I agree that it is best to just raise an exception.

Answer (score 0):

You could use two methods on your detach class:

**is_finished()**
Tells you if the function call is still being executed.

**get_data()**
Will get you the return values of your detached_func. If the function has not finished yet, it blocks until the function is finished.

I do not know any python standards, but you can look at Java's Future class which wraps the result of a task that is executed asynchronously.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html